# Hacker News mysteriously blocked on my Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, browser, dns, proxy

When I try to access http://news.ycombinator.com on my computer, I get

```
502 proxy error:
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

This happens in all browsers (even wget on the command line results in `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.`).

All other URLs work fine, ping works fine and seems to resolve to the correct IP

```
PING news.ycombinator.com (174.132.225.106): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 174.132.225.106: icmp_seq=0 ttl=51 time=65.657 ms
```

At first I thought Hacker News was down, but then I realized it works on other people's computers. I am able to get to the listings from hckrnews.com (which even has a nicer interface), but cannot access any of the comments.

I am the only one with access to my computer. I then thought it might be a Chrome plugin, but given that it happens in all browsers, and wget, that can't be it.

Comment: @Moab Read the title. // Stian, do you have any proxy servers set up on that system? Tried a different DNS? Can you reach the site by IP?